# НАТОвские или натовские — как правильно?

Tags: аббревиатура

Надо ли в слове "натовские" (войска) выделять прописными аббревиатуру "НАТО"?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо. Причина, конечно, не в том, что аббревиатура "не русская" (это, кстати, весьма спорно). 
В производных от аббревиатур словах заглавные не используются (кроме первой буквы, если это требуется по общим правилам).

Я не нашел, где подобное сказано в явном виде, но это вполне вытекает из текста справочника "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" Лопатина
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95

§ 204. Буквенные аббревиатуры обычно пишутся прописными буквами, напр.: МГУ, СНГ, ФРГ, ЭВМ, ПТУ, ЦК, ФБР.

Значительно реже используется другой способ написания буквенных аббревиатур, направленный на передачу звучания слов, — по названиям букв, напр.: эсер (сокращение слов: социалист-революционер), цеу (ценное указание). Некоторые буквенные аббревиатуры могут писаться двояко — по буквам и по их названиям, напр.: ЧП и чепэ (чрезвычайное происшествие), БТР и бэтээр (бронетранспортёр), ЧК и Чека.

В формах склонения буквенных аббревиатур и в ***словах, образованных от буквенных аббревиатур с помощью суффиксов, используется только второй способ передачи аббревиатурной основы — по названиям букв***, напр.: бэтээры (от БТР), кагэбэшник (от КГБ), гэбист (от ГБ), кавээнщик (от КВН), цековский (от ЦК), цеэсковский (от ЦСКА), эсэнгэвский (от СНГ), кабэшный (от КБ), гэпэушный (от ГПУ).

*(Курсив мой - b-s)*

Answer (score 0):

[Нет.](http://lopatin.academic.ru/73591/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) НАТО - не русская аббревиатура и воспринимается как отдельное слово. Видимо поэтому при образовании производных слов корень не выделяют.

Comment: Марк Из, будьте добры написать ответ полным, а то все-таки ссылка из одного слова не совсем хорошо смотрится.  
Спасибо.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, исправил.